# add a class to the ui-view based on the current state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In a AngularJS (1.2.7) project, using UI Router (0.2.8), I want to apply the current state as a class to the ui-view element, because that would allow me to apply animations for specific states, e.g. do transition A going from login to start and do transition B going from start to settings.

At the moment I have the $state object on the $rootScope (as [mentioned here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/561), which allows me to add a state-based class on the body using ng-class="$state.current.name". However, if I add that to the ui-view element, e.g.

```
<div ui-view ng-class="$state.current.name"></div>
```

Then the class is one step behind the actual state. So when going from "login" to "start", the class will be "login" instead of "start".

Comment: May not be wise but did you tried `<div ui-view class="{{$state.current.name}}"></div>`

Comment: @Satpal Yeah, that gives the same result as using ng-class.

Comment: TIL that you can set ng-class to a string

Comment: did you fix this Ron?

Comment: @williamsowen We ended up using brisky's solution. I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Ron - cheers, this all works great.  But it doesn't seem to bind the class before `ng-enter`.  So I can't animate the initial entrance of the view - no problem animating `ng-leave` etc.  Have you managed this by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a bug, you can read more about the issue here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/866

Until it is fixed I suggest such a workaround:

```
<div ng-class="$state.current.name"><div ui-view></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading between the lines of what I think you're trying to do: you want to style a particular view differently depending on the state/route. Here's what I'm doing currently:

1) Set a state attribute on the HTML element:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl" state="{{ state }}">
    <div ui-view="nav"></div>
    <div ui-view="page" autoscroll="true"></div>
</html>
```

2) Update the state name whenever the route changes:

```
app.controller('MyAppCtrl', function($rootScope){

  $rootScope.state = 'home';

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
    $rootScope.state = toState.name;
  });

});
```

3) Using attribute selectors in the stylesheets:

```
[state="app.articles"] [ui-view="page"] {
  section {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding $state to $rootScope I just put a method on the controller of my root directive that returns the active state name.  Then I added to the DOM like so:

```
<ui-view active-state="{{ctrl.getActiveState()}}"></ui-view>
```

Then in my CSS I can use selectors like this:

```
[active-state="someStateName"] { ... }
```

If you prefer a class it would be just as easy to do this:

```
<ui-view class="{{ctrl.getActiveState()}}"></ui-view>
```

...but you would want to replace all "." characters with "-" in your getActiveState() method.

Answer (score 0):

but, i has question about that : `<div ng-class="$state.current.name"><div ui-view></div></div>`

`$state.current.name`   equal  `user.login`  hou to code my css?

Comment: and how to replace the dot in the classname

Comment: I got how to do it ` .controller('nameCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state){$state.className = 'your class name'}])`