# Apply a state class to ui-view to allow different ng animation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I need to apply different animations depending on the current state using `ui-view`.  Following on from [this question..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308563/add-a-class-to-the-ui-view-based-on-the-current-state)

I have the following code (edit: see [plunker preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/3QjBzRu5VjOzK7czn71e?p=preview))

```
<section ui-view ng-class="stateClass"></section>
```

`stateClass` gets applied in each controller e.g:

```
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $state) {
  // Set state class name
  $scope.stateClass = 'slide-left';
  console.log($scope);
```

This works and the class gets added fine - but the animation wont kick in.

If I was to update the `ui-view` code to:

```
<section ui-view class="slide-left"></section>
```

with the class hardcoded, this works (but now I can't apply different animations).

Does `ng-class` get added after `ng-enter`? Can someone suggest how to achieve the animations?

edit>> Oddly enough `ng-leave` animations work fine.  But css still doesn't apply to `ng-enter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your ui-view following directive `state-class`:

```
.directive('stateClass', ['$state', function($state) {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var stateName = $state.current.name || 'init',
                normalizedStateName = 'state-' + stateName.replace(/\./g, '-');
            $element.addClass(normalizedStateName);
        }
    }
}]);
```

On `ng-enter`, for newly created element it will add current state name (the state the ui-view makes the transition to). For the element that is going to disappear the state remains the same as it was created before.

For example:

The transition from `main` to `modal` state:

Phase 1: The `main` state is active:

```
<ui-view state-class class="state-main ng-scope"></ui-view>
```

Phase 2: Run `$state.go('modal');`

```
<ui-view state-class class="state-modal ng-animate ng-enter ng-enter-active"></ui-view>
<ui-view state-class class="state-main ng-animate ng-leave ng-leave-active"></ui-view>
```

Phase 3: The `modal` state is active

```
<ui-view state-class class="state-modal"></ui-view>
```